# Push Notification Unsuccessful -- why?

Tags: ruby, apple-push-notifications

Trying to test a push notification using [nomad/houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston), but it simply says unsuccessful. How can I debug and figure out why it isn't working?

```
$ TOKEN="< .. token ..>"
$ apn push $TOKEN -c apn.pem -m "testing testing" -e development -p
Password: *****
8 push notifications sent successfully
8 push notifications unsuccessful ()
```

This is the second time around, first time got all sorts of key errors.

**Edit:**

The issue was not quoting the bash variable. Stupid! The hint was 8 notifications, with only one token. The fix:

```
$ apn push "$TOKEN" -c apn.pem -m "message"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just [junky code](https://github.com/nomad/houston/blob/c235ebd923b4b59a32001444798618d7d91be2c9/bin/apn) to me:

`apn` source:

```
case sent.length
when 1
  say_ok "#{sent.length} push notification sent successfully"
else
  say_ok "#{sent.length} push notifications sent successfully"
end

case unsent.length
when 1
  say_ok "#{sent.length} push notification unsuccessful (#{unsent.join(", ")})"
else
  say_ok "#{sent.length} push notifications unsuccessful (#{unsent.join(", ")})"
end
```

When `unsent.length` is zero, it says an error message using the wrong variable.  Dumb.